# How to import 100 million rows table into database?

Tags: mysql, database

Can any one guide me about my query?, i m making application for banking sector with fuzzy logic. i have to import table with 100 million rows daily. and i am using MySql for this application which is processing slowly. so is there any another server for handling my database which can access fast?

Comment: 100M rows **daily** and you've no DBA?

Comment: Thanks Denis, but our organization don't has any DBA for this. So can you Please guide me?

Comment: 100M daily is over 1k inserts per second. The best advice I can give you is that your organization ***needs*** a DBA. See lesson #1 [right here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200262/how-to-import-100-million-rows-table-into-database).

Comment: If you want to act as the DBA and seek advice here, you'll first have to provide more details on how the (slow) import is done now.

Comment: After reading http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/07/05/working-with-large-data-sets-in-mysql/ it seems that you will need MySql expertise, otherwise there would be trouble somewhere down the line.

Comment: thanks ypercude, it takes 2-3 hours to import that file.

Comment: Ask this question on Database Administrators: http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

100 million rows daily?

You have to be realistic. I doubt any single instance of *any database* out there can handle this type of thouroughput efficiently.  You should probably look at clustering options and other optimising techniques such as splitting data in two diffent DB's (sharding).

[MySQL Enterprise](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/features.html) has a bunch of features built-in that could ease and moniter the clustering process, but I think MySQL community edition supports it too.

Good-luck!

Answer (score 6):

We roughly load about half that many rows a day in our RDBMS (Oracle) and it would not occur to me to implement such a thing without access to DBA knowledge about my RDBMS. We fine-tune this system several times a month and we still encounter new issues all the time. This is such a non-trivial task that the only valid answer is:

**Don't play around, have your managers get a DBA who knows their business!**

Note: Our system has been in place for 10 years now. It hasn't been built in a day...

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing it?
One hugh transaction?

Perhaps try to make small transactions in chunks of 100 or 1000.

Is there an index on that table? Drop the index before starting the improt (if that is possible due to unique costraints etc.) and rebuild the index after the import.

An other option would perhaps be an in memory database.

Comment: Thanks Angel, there is no index on that table but still it takes much time to process.please guide me.

Comment: why do you recommend only processing 100 - 1000 records at a time? Isn't there a lot of energy spent on startup and stopping for each batch?

Comment: @DOK: The problem is that a database needs to keep a journal for the case of rollback. That can lead to a lot of additional memory/concurrency overhead, especially if the batch job is not the only process accessing the updated table

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems your business' main logic does not depend on importing those 100mio rows into a database, otherwise you wouldn't be stuck with doing this by yourself, right? (correct me if I'm wrong)

Are you sure you need to import those rows into a database when the main business doesn't need to? What kind of questions are you going to ask of the date? Can't you maybe keep the log files on a bunch of servers and query them with eg Hadoop? Or can you aggregate the information contained in the log files and only store a condensed version?

I'm also asking this because it sounds like you're planning to perform some at least moderately sophisticated analysis on the data and the trouble with this amount of data won't stop once you have it in a DB.

Comment: To me, this sounds like batch-loading transactions / securities data, not necessarily log data

Comment: true log data is poorly worded by me, but shouldn't that be the same type of data?